# How to use Vagrant for CentOS with GUI

Tags: qt, centos, vagrant

I am trying to up a Vagrant machine with CentOS version with GUI. Here is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm"
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.name = "DSW-Run-7"
end
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.13"
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/CartoDSW"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
# Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
vb.gui = true
  vb.memory = "2048"
end
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install qt5-qtbase
sudo yum -y install qt5-qtbase-devel
sudo yum -y install jbigkit.x86_64
sudo yum -y install gcc-c++
sudo yum -y install git
sudo yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts
  SHELL
end
```

After this I did `vagrant up` and the GUI is up. I tried to login with Vagrant, but Vagrant says 'invalid login':

> Centos Linux 7 (core)
>
> kernel 3.10.0-123.e17.x86_64
>
> localhost login:vagrant
>
> password:password
>
> Login incorrect

After `vagrant up` I did `vagrant ssh` and used commands such as `startx`, but still not able to launch the GUI.

Please suggest how I can install CentOS with GUI, as I need to work with QT to debug my code.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this for Centos/7 I installed and launched the GNOME from Vagrant file with the following shell commands:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
 sudo yum -y groupinstall "GNOME Desktop"
 sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
 sudo systemctl start graphical.target
SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS 6, I have a repo got it work here: https://github.com/hsiaoyi0504/vagrant_centos_6_gui.

In short, use following codes to install and set up:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  # install GUI desktop
  sudo yum update
  sudo yum groupinstall -y "X Window System" "Desktop"
  sudo yum install -y gnome-core xfce4 xorg-x11-fonts
  sudo echo "id:5:initdefault:" > /etc/inittab
  # fix fonts problem in terminal
  # https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/fonts-screwed-up-in-centos-6-terminal.2186468/
  sudo yum -y install terminus-fonts terminus-fonts-console
  reboot # reboot to load GUI
SHELL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 potential solutions:

- first : using a GUI and boot the GUI directly
- second : using x11 forwarding

**First Option : Boot in GUI mode**

vagrant user has no password in most cases (unless you specified otherwise and build a new box) as it connects with ssh key.

If you want to connect via GUI, you'll need to give the user a new password.

- run `vagrant ssh` to connect into the VM
- run `sudo passwd` to enter a new password for your user

From there you will be able to login via GUI and then make sure you have X environment to start working on, you can install

```
sudo yum install 'xorg*'
sudo yum install xterm
```

or to install a Gnome environment

```
yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"
```

Make sure to set your Vagrantfile with

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

and your GUI will boot when you run `vagrant up`

**The Alternative, your second option : use X11 forwarding**

From what you try to achieve, there might be a better way (but I am not familiar enough with QT to really judge). Vagrant has an option to forward X11.

> `config.ssh.forward_x11` - If `true`, X11 forwarding over SSH
>   connections is enabled. Defaults to false.

You will need a X11 client on your host (If you run on mac you can download and use [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) it does the job pretty well, if you're running on another system, check for an equivalent)

So when you have your X11 client installed on your host and turn on `config.ssh.forward_x11` you can run directly X-command and they will be forwarded on your host so

```
sudo yum install xterm
xterm &
```

and the xterm window will appear on your host machine.

Note: you may need to install `xauth` on the VM, using e.g. `sudo apt-get install xauth` (Debian/Ubuntu/...) or `yum install xorg-x11-xauth` (CentOS, Fedora, ...).

Comment: that worked out perfectly.I am able to login and then i tried to install as desktop with UI as yum groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts and did sudo startx, desktop is not opening. My aim is to have centos machine to work on QT GUI and debug my code (probably through GDB). Please suggest me how doi do it.

Comment: @sasikala thats because x-environment is probably not installed, installed with `sudo yum install 'xorg*'` also might be a better way detailed in the edit of my answer using X11 forwarding

Comment: @Henri after login to GUI, i ran 4 commands sudo yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
      sudo yum clean all 
      sudo yum update
      sudo yum reinstall NetworkManager After these commands I did vagrant reload from my terminal, then login through GUI to host machine and when I do sudo startx, centos machine is up with a desktop. But if i run these commands from vagrantfile , I am getting error as startx command not found. I think from vagrant file not able to install GNOME Desktop. Any Idea on how to do it from Vagrantfile.

Comment: how do you run startx from Vagrantfile ? by default it would be root user, make sure vagrant user runs command; also I am not even sure this is possible. The 2 options I know are : 1. x11 forwarding and 2. login via GUI

Comment: startx i can do from GUI. I added sudo yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"  to vagrantfile but seems Desktop is not installed because when i do startx command it says command not found. I would like to add GNOME desktop from vagrantfile.

Comment: sorry to ask you many time. I am using mac and i added sudo yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"  this command to vagrant file and did vagrant up from command line. afetr vagrant is up, i connected as vagrant ssh and used command startx to start GUI but it says startx command not found. am I doing anything wrong.I added config.ssh.forward_x11 = true also. do i need to run startx on CLI after vagrant ssh or from GUI which is enabled with vb.gui=true?

Comment: the `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"` must be run from the VM, not from the host - so vagrant ssh, then install, then startx

Comment: did you read the answer ? if you do `config.ssh.forward_x11` you need to install Xquartz on your host and it will start up automatically when you run a Xcommand from the VM

Comment: so we cannot install centos with gui from vagrantfile?after adding minimal centos box through vagrantfile , do vagrant ssh, install and startx ri8?

Comment: if you have `vb.gui = true` GUI will boot automatically when you do `vagrant up`
 - I think you should spend some time to try on your end. Good thing with vagrant is that you can always destroy if everything is broken and restart without damage

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into your Vagrantfile, to reset passwords. Works on Centos 6x images I typically use

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"vagrant\"|passwd --stdin vagrant"
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"vagrant\"|passwd --stdin root"
```

For example:

https://github.com/lastnitescurry/documentum71/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Figured it out from:

https://github.com/puphpet/packer-templates/blob/master/centos-6-x86_64/http/ks.cfg